# Is it possible to work with core data if I fogot to enable core data when project creates in ios

Tags: ios, core-data

As we know if want to work with core data in ios, when we create the project we have to enable `core data` at the begining.but unfortunately I couldn't do that.
but now I want to use `core data` for my project.so these are my questions.

- is it possible to add `core data` now (to work with core data now).
- if it is possible, how can I do that.
- how can I check that I have enabled core data when I create the project.

hope your help with this.thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can. 
The steps needed are:

1. Added a new Model file. Go to File -> New -> File... -> Core Data -> Data Model, and enter the data model name. It will create a file with extension `.xcdatamodeld`
2. Write core data initializers for `NSManagedObjectContext`, `NSManagedObjectModel` and `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`.

For the second step, I would suggest you create a new test core-data project and copy-paste the Core Data stack code from the test project's AppDelegate to your existing project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add core data. Please create a new coredata model. (File>New>File...>iOS>Core Data>Data Model)